# Looping through a variable in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, if-statement, while-loop

I'm trying to conditionally check a variable and iterate through a while loop, but I've not been able to get it.
Here is the snippet.

```
if(bla==""){
  //Processing something
} else {
  while(bla==""){
    //iterating variable 'bla' till it becomes ""(blank)
    //Processing something
  }
}
```

First I check if a variable `bla` is blank and then do the processing. Otherwise I iterate the variable `bla` until it becomes blank in the while condition, and then do the same processing.

How can it be done?

Comment: what errors are you running into? The code looks ok to me

Comment: Your code seems correct. What is not working with your solutiuon?

Comment: `while(bla=="")` will loop while it is an empty string, not until it becomes one.

Comment: if you want to loop **until it becomes blank** - the loop should be true **until it becomes blank** ... so `while(bla!=="")`

Comment: It goes into infinite loop if in the first run the variable `bla` is not blank

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IF you want to iterate variable 'bla' till it becomes ""(blank) you need to put condition as `while(bla != "")`

```
if (bla == "") {
  //Processing something
} else {
  while (bla != "") {
    //iterating variable 'bla' till it becomes ""(blank)

  }
  //Processing something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This may do the trick :

```js
while(bla==""){
   //iterating variable 'bla' till it becomes ""(blank)
   //Processing something
}

if(bla === ""){
  //Processing something when bla is empty

}
```